# How to fire a custom event to trigger partial form validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

Iam trying to validate my form step by step on clicking a button called 'next'.
Is there a way to fire a custom event to trigger partial form validation?
Something like that:

```
<input type="text" id="age-id" name="age" 
  ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'ValidateStepOne'}" 
  min="18"
  max="99"
  ng-model="data.age"
>
```

Triggering the event onclick at a button:

```
$scope.validate = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('ValidateStepOne');
};
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated.
Kind regards

OliverKK

Comment: More code would be helpful to understand the layout more.  But if you have your UI setup like I am thinking you could make each step its own form so button submit would cause form validation for that step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The validation of the steps is a pre validation before POSTing the formular. It's not an option to separate the form into subforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was separating the huge form into sub forms(thanks to @fiskers7), which is pretty handy.
The validation takes place by using a [custom trigger](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-triggers) on clicking at the 
`next` button to validate the current step.
The `required` validator and other used validators will be executed when the custom submit event is fired.

```
    <form id="form1" ng-submit="validate(1)" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" novalidate>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" required>
      <span ng-show="form1.$submitted && form1['name'].$error.required">Name is required!</span>
      <input type="submit" value="next">
    </form>

    <form id="form2" ng-submit="validate(2)" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" novalidate>
      <input type="text" ng-model="surename" required> 
      <span ng-show="form2.$submitted && form1['surename'].$error.required">Name is required!</span>
      <input type="submit" value="next">
    </form>
```

The validation function `submit` within the controller looks like this:

```
 $scope.validate = function(num) {
    $scope['form' + num].$setSubmitted(true);
    if (!$scope['form' + num].$valid) {
      $scope.scrollToTop();
    } else if (num < $scope.maxSteps) {
      $scope.next(num + 1);
    } else {
      $scope.submit();
    }
  }
```

**See the AngularJS Documentation for more details: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms**

Kind regards

OliverKK

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your form into several pieces that use `ng-if` to decide whether to show them or not.

```
<form action="" name="myForm">
    <div ng-if="step == 1">
        <input type="text" required="true" name="input1" ng-model="inputVal1"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="step == 2">
        <input type="text" required="true" name="input2" ng-model="inputVal2"/>
    </div>            
</form>
```

see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/v52apyzh/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your answere. In the beginning i was doing it like your suggestion. But it turned out that it would be better to separate the huge form in smaller forms. The key point on doing this is, each form does have it's own submit button, which makes the validation pretty simple.